# A generalised formula for $\cos {n\theta}$ in terms of powers of $\cosθ$ using De Moivre's Theroem

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

I am trying to generalise a formula for $\cos{nθ}$ in terms of powers of $\cosθ$ using De Moivre's Theorem for a high school assignment.
The equations are here:

[image]

I was wondering if letting $m= ⌊n/2⌋-j+k$, and changing the variable of the summation like that is valid.

Comment: Only if you are careful about all the variables and make sure the sum keeps an integer value for the upper bound, then any algebraic manipulation is fine.

Comment: It's worth noting that such expressions ($\cos n\theta$ in terms of powers of $\cos\theta$) are well-documented as the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind $T_n(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html), i.e. $\cos n\theta =T_n(\cos\theta)$.

Comment: Summation notation implies integer steps. So in your line 3, j takes the values 0, 1, 2, ... up to floor n/2. However this misses half the terms. The j=1 term from line 2 is missing from line 3, which makes that step not valid. You would somehow have to indicate that your summation goes over every integer _and half-integer_ from 0 to floor n/2. The standard way to do this is just keep your summation index as in line 2.